# Working with AWS- Django and MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have developed my application using mongoDB as the database and Django framework and I intend to use AWS services.

I visited the AWS site and there were many products that confused me, so with the above stack what would be the most viable solution to work with AWS

Comment: What do you want to do with AWS? You can use AWS to deploy Django or use s3 for file storage...

Comment: @1GDST I want to deploy Django which will be acting as a backend for my app. The database is  mongodb.

Comment: This is what you need: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two EC2 instances one for Django and other one for MongoDB.

For MongoDB you require EC2 with EBS(Elastic Block Storage) volumes to store persistent data or else you can give a try to [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas).